# Rails scope for nil or blank in one of the variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create a scope that returns the records that have a value of nil or '' in either of two columns?

What I've come up with is:

`scope :missing_coordinates, -> { where("latitude = '' OR longitude = ''") }`

but maybe there is a fancier way to do it as usual in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting but more verbose way (so less railsy as it's longer but more railsy as it uses chained scopes) is you can chain scopes and if on Rails5 use ActiveRecord's OR like:

```
scope :bad_longitude, -> { where(longitude: '') #This will return all nil and blanks
scope :bad_latitude, -> { where(latitude: '' )

scope :missing_coordinates, -> {bad_longitude.or(bad_latitude) }
```

I would keep it your way in this situation but if your scope becomes more complex I'd swap to chaining scopes as it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Could do. Does comparing by ' ' also consider nils?

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon No it won't, you'd want `where(longitude: ['', nil])` or `where("coalesce(longitude, '') = ''")` to cover NULLs. I'd recommend that you update your models to convert `''` to `nil` (and fix the database) so that you only have one "missing value".

Comment: Makes sense, nice tip. Thank you